# Does ggplot use dynamic function for statistic functions?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, stat

So I'm running an optimization problem and am trying to add the function at each point in time to a plot. I'm able to plot the function but I have the variables stored and it seems like r doesn't evaluate the function until it renders it. It's hard to explain, but I have a simple example that shows it.

```
data = data.frame(x = runif(20, -10, 10), y = runif(20, -10,10))
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y =y))
slope = 0.5
yoff = 1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) slope*x+yoff)
slope = 1
yoff = -1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) slope*x+yoff)
p
```

And what I want is two lines on the graph with the slope and y-intercept that I had when I added the function to the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of them, make a list of functions:

```
make_fun <- function(slope,yoff) {slope; yoff; function(x) x*slope + yoff}
> l <- mapply(FUN = make_fun,slope = 1:2,yoff = 3:4)
> l[[1]](1)
[1] 4
> l[[2]](1)
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A function is evaluated when used, so there it is at render time.
You can rename your parameters to have different function:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y =y))
slope1 = 0.5
yoff1 = 1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) slope1*x+yoff1)
slope2 = 1
yoff2 = -1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) slope2*x+yoff2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many parameters in ggplot aren't evaluated until the plot is actually rendered. Here we can make the `slope` and `yoff` values arguments to the functions and then pass in values via the `args=` parameter which does get evaluated earlier.

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(x = runif(20, -10, 10), y = runif(20, -10,10))
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y =y))
slope = 0.5
yoff = 1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x, slope, yoff) slope*x+yoff, args=list(slope=slope, yoff=yoff))
slope = 1
yoff = -1
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x, slope, yoff) slope*x+yoff, args=list(slope=slope, yoff=yoff))
p
```